# Can I transfer my trinkets from my weapons to the ones I find in the field?

Tags: deathloop

I just found a new weapon that I want to swap with my current weapon. My current weapon currently has some trinkets attached to it. Can I take my trinkets off my current weapon and transfer to the new weapon so I can keep it all? Or do I have to leave my trinkets behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a bit further in the game, I'm getting the feeling that this ultimately doesn't matter.

Early on with each loop and time of day, it appears all drops will be the same. Enemies seem to carry the same weapons with same level and upgrades, trinkets, everything. And since you don't keep your items at the end of the loop, you could just reacquire them later on.

However later on, you'll get the chance to "buy" the chance to keep weapons and trinkets. And chances are, the weapon you'll swap out is a weapon with trinkets attached that you "bought." You'll get them back in the next loop so it's effectively the same, just it won't be available til the next run.

So in the end, it doesn't look like you can transfer trinkets but it doesn't really matter. The trinkets you have equipped you'll likely have "bought" them so it will continue on with you in future loops.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can unequip trinkets.  On PC you do it by holding <kbd>Del</kbd> in the trinket menu.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't swap trinkets in the field. If you leave a gun behind then you leave behind its equipped trinkets too.

However, every loop gives an opportunity to get them again, and any trinkets (or weapons) that were infused when you left them behind will be returned to you.